# How to test an external HTTP resource using mocha and requestify

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, requestify

I am trying to do a simple test of an external HTTP resource using mocha.  Here is my code:

```
describe('bing.com', function() {
    it('should return 200 for a GET request', function() {
        var requestify = require('requestify');

        requestify.get('http://bing.com')
            .then(function(response) {
                // Get the response body (JSON parsed or jQuery object for XMLs)
                console.log(response.getBody());
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

The test just says passed but my `console.log` call is never shown.  Is mocha completing before the http response is received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide the `done` callback to your test function:

`describe('bing.com', function() {
    it('should return 200 for a GET request', function(done) {
...`

To catch errors like that you should check your Code with JSHint (or Jslint). Both would inform you that your `done()` call won't work as the variable is not defined.